# Can dried beans be pickled/fermented?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, beans, fermentation

Can dry beans, when soaked, be pickled/fermented, such as in vinegar or brine? Or would there be too much phytic acid in them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Besides soy, can other types of beans be fermeted?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/97511/besides-soy-can-other-types-of-beans-be-fermeted)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other question.  I've flagged it to close.  Please try not to submit multiple, overlapping, questions at once, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beans can be reconstituted and fermented or pickled.  While there is some controversy over whether or not phytic acid in legumes is problematic or not, most agree that soaking, cooking, sprouting, and fermentation all contribute to the the reduction of phytic acid.

Comment: So uncooked soaked beans can be fermented, or do they have to be cooked first? That's interesting that even soaking and fermenting reduces phytic acid levels.

Comment: @Geremia  see the response to your other question on bean fermentation.