# Besides soy, can other types of beans be fermented?

Tags: food-preservation, beans, fermentation, soy

Besides soy beans, can other types of beans be fermented?

Comment: In theory anything that have carbs in it can be fermented (apart from tomatoes. I never was able to ferment tomatoes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, any bean can be fermented.  Black bean is common, for example, but you can certainly experiment.  [This site might be a good starting point.](https://www.culturesforhealth.com/learn/natural-fermentation/fermenting-beans-and-legumes/) They recommend rehydration, then cooking, prior to fermentation. They recommend using yogurt, a commercial starter culture, or a brine from lacto-fermented vegetables to get the process going.